# "Despite not being" vs "despite of not being"

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions

What's the different between *despite not being* and *despite of not being*?

Example:

> She wore a turtleneck sweater and a floral skirt that reached just
>   above her knee. **Despite (of) not being expensive clothes, they made
>   her look elegant.**

Will the meaning change if I choose one from the other? Or maybe one of them is ungrammatical?

Comment: This link may help:http://www.englishgrammar.org/spite-3/

Comment: The difference is that 'despite of not being' is not used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Despite Ø not being* is the only correct form.  If you've seen someone use *Despite **of***, it's probably due to influence from the synonymous phrase *in spite of*, which does need the preposition.